# Check if a personProperty exists on PeopleManager

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I have the following code to retrieve data from users within the AD:

```
PeopleManager peopleManager = new PeopleManager(clientContext);
PersonProperties personProperties = peopleManager.GetPropertiesFor(loginName);
clientContext.Load(personProperties);
clientContext.Load(personProperties, p => p.AccountName, p => p.UserProfileProperties);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

var personalUrl=personProperties.PersonalUrl;
```

That last line throws an error on *some* but not on all users:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerObjectNullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object on server. The object is associated with method GetPropertiesFor.
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject.CheckUninitializedProperty(String propName)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.PersonProperties.get_PersonalUrl()

So simply spoken: Is there a method to check if that property is set before trying to retrieve the value?

Or is a `try..catch` the only (ugly) way to solve this?

Comment: If the last line is throwing an error for few, isnt that personProperties null?

Comment: No. it isn't ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PersonProperties object has IsPropertyAvailable method that returns a Boolean value depending upon whether the property is set or not.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee546589.aspx

So the last line needs to be replaced by:

```
string personalUrl=personProperties.IsPropertyAvailable("PersonalUrl")?personProperties.PersonalUrl:null;
```